# Is probability perspective dependent?

Tags: experimental-mathematics

Suppose there be a person 'A' doing coin unbiased coin flips and he gets 4 heads in a row, then the chance of the next being a tail is 97%, which is very very likely. 
 But if person 'B' unaware of 'A' doing an experiment, takes the same coin and flips it, will the probability of him getting a tail or head be 50%?, will it be influenced by the 'A'?
 Is probability a perspective truth?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yeah, but the experimenter himself doesn't know of event A happening. But as distant observers, we do know. So, is the answer 50% correct for a tail or 97% correct? Given the toss is the same.

Comment: Simply put, in the case of gambling, can I influence the next card pick at a counter by picking a card from a deck which is no way connected to it. But as far as distributions go, the draws show a pattern, so does it magically affect the other picks?

Comment: If it's an unbiased coin, the probability is 50%. No memory. If the coin might be biased, person 'A' could guess that the probability of *heads* on the next flip is higher, while person 'B' cannot do that. My Bayesian friends can give you hints about this situation.

Comment: It is the [Gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) . Also this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1125087/435814) is relevant.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you so much. The post was exactly what I wanted.:)